# Key bindings up arrow is not recognized for the first time

Tags: java, swing, action, key-bindings, jtextcomponent

I have used **keybindings** for up arrow action,

However it doesn't seem to work for the first time and it works from second press as i implemented,

Below is my code,

```
    txtLog = new JTextArea();    
    Action upArrowAction = new UpArrowAction();
    txtLog.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_UP,0), "upArrow");
    txtLog.getActionMap().put("upArrow", upArrowAction);
```

in uparrow call,

```
    class UpArrowAction extends AbstractAction{         
    @Override        
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {           
        .....
    }
```

The UpArrowAction is called for the second time and not for the first time ..

Please help..

Comment: Try `txtLog.getInputMap(WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW)` - the default `getInputMap()` is the same as `getInputMap(WHEN_FOCUSED)` meaning that keybinding will work only when the `txtLog` is already has focus.

Comment: no idea from posted description, nor from code, please whats your goal, [list of built_in KeyBindings](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/10/key-bindings/), by @camickr, and here are TextActions too, to test if isn't there concurency before you are post an SSCCE / MCVE / MCTRE, short, runnable, compilable caused by a.m. issue